# AWS CloudWatch with mobile applications

Tags: xamarin.forms, amazon-cloudwatch, nlog, visual-studio-app-center

I have a backend system built in AWS and I'm utilizing CloudWatch in all of the services for logging and monitoring. I really like the ability to send structured JSON logs into CloudWatch that are consistent and provide a lot of context around the log message. Querying the logs and getting to the root of an issue is simple or just exploring the health of the environment - makes CloudWatch a must have for my backend.

Now I'm working on the frontend side of things, mobile applications using Xamarin.Forms. I know AWS has Amplify but I really wanted to stick with Xamarin.Forms as that's a skill set I've already got and I'm comfortable with. Since Amplify didn't support Xamarin.Forms I've been stuck looking at other options for logging - one of them being Microsoft's AppCenter.

If I go the AppCenter route I'll end up having to build out a mapping of the AppCenter installation identifier and my users between the AWS environment and the AppCenter environment. Before I start down that path I wanted to ask a couple questions around best practice and security of an alternative approach.

I'm considering using the AWS SDK for .Net, creating an IAM Role with a Policy that allows for X-Ray and CloudWatch PUT operations on a specific log group and then assigning it to an IAM User. I can issue access keys for the user and embed them in my apps config files. This would let me send log data right into CloudWatch from the mobile apps using something like NLog.

I noticed with AppCenter I have to provide a client secret to the app, which wouldn't be any different than providing an IAM User access key to my app for pushing into CloudWatch. I'm typically a little shy about issuing access keys from AWS but as long as the Policy is tight I can't think of any negative side-effects... other than someone flooding me with log data should they pull the key out of the app data.

An alternative route I'm exploring is instead of embedding the access keys in my config files - I could request them from my API services and hold it in-memory. Only downside to that is when the user doesn't have internet connectivity logging might be a pain (will need to look at how NLog handles sinks that aren't currently available - queueing and flushing)

Is there anything else I'm not considering or is this approach a feasible solution with minimal risk?

Comment: did you get the answer to it?

Comment: I ended up going with a restricted policy and using the access key. The security risk was minimal with them being able to list my Cloudwatch log groups and write to a specific one.